# 5-dimensional plotting in matlab for classification

Tags: matlab

I want to create a 5 dimensional plotting in matlab. I have two files in my workspace. one is data(150*4). In this file, I have 150 data and each has 4 features. Since I want to classify them, I have another file called "labels" (150*1) that includes a label for each data in data files. In other words the label are the class of data and I have 3 class: 1,2,3
I want to plot this classification, but i can't...

Naris

Comment: How exactly do you want the five dimensions to appear, and what makes it that you 'can't'? If you get an error please specify the error message, otherwise try to post a small snippet to show the data that you want to plot (for example `rand(10,2,2,2,2)` )

Comment: my data is in an excel file. each row is a sample with 4 features(columns). and i have 150 data(rows).

Comment: i have another excel file that has 150 rows and each row shows the label of the class for each data. I have 3 labels ( 3 classes):1,2,3. now I want to plot my data by a point for each data which has a color( for example: red. green.blue)     Naris

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scatter3` to plot your data, using three features of `data` as dimensions, the fourth as color, and the class as different markers

```
figure,hold on
markerList = 'o*+';
for iClass = 1:nClasses
    classIdx = dataClass==iClass;
    scatter3(data(classIdx,1),data(classIdx,2),data(classIdx,3),[],data(classIdx,4),...
       'marker',markerList(iClass));
end
```

When you use color to represent one of the features, I suggest to use a good colormap, such as [pmkmp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28982-perceptually-improved-colormaps/content/pmkmp.m) from the Matlab File Exchange instead of the default `jet`.

Alternatively, you can use e.g. `mdscale` to transform your higher-dimensional data to 2D for standard plotting.

Comment: It's still going on a 2-D screen, so you're only getting 4 dimensions.  Marker size can be added as a fifth.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, but you can rotate the plot to have your brain restore the third dimension. Marker size can be tricky to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what kind of plot you want to see. 5 dimensions are difficult to visualize, unless of course, your hyper-dimensional monitor is working. Mine never came back from the repair shop. (That should teach me for sending it out.)

Seriously, 5 dimensional data really can be difficult to visualize. The usual solution is to plot points in a 2-d space (the screen coordinates of a figure, for example. This is what plot essentially does.) Then use various attributes of the points plotted to show the other three dimensions. This is what Chernoff faces do for you. If you have the stats toolbox, then it looks like glyphplot will help you out. Or you can plot in 3-d, then use two attributes to show the other two dimensions.

Another idea is to plot points in 2-d to show two of the dimensions, then use color to indicate the other three dimensions. Thus, the RGB assigned to that marker will be defined by the other three dimensions. Of course, that means you must be able to visualize what the RGB coordinates of a color represent, so you need to understand color as it is represented in an RGB space.

Answer (score 0):

There's a model called SOM (Self-organizing Maps) which builds a 2-D image of a multidimensional space.